# trying to create a token on mainnet-beta. constantly getting this error

Tags: spl-token, mainnet

HTTP status client error (429 Too Many Requests) for url (https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/)

What should I do to create a token?

Answer (score 1):

you have tried too many times and sent more requests than allowed, here you can find the limits:
https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints#mainnet-beta

the simple answer is you should just wait, how long should be in the [Retry-After](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) response you received. Alternative you could try and use another RPC provider if you know how to configure it.

once you are allowed to make requests again you can create your own token using the CLI something like this:
https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/sol-mint-token

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried too many times. I think it is because of the version of tools that i used. I installed newer version and tokens are created at first try.